# Facebook multiple sharing buttons on same page

Tags: facebook, image, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-sharer

I have a problem with sharing multiple images/posts with Facebook.

The scenario is this:

We develop a social network, and on the news feed we display posts which contain images.
When we click on an image from the news feed, we get a redirect to the image page, where we display the owner of the image, the image itself, comments, likes, etc.

For each image post from the news feed we added a share facebook link. What we want to accomplish is that when the user clicks on share facebook link then facebook would pick up the  image src and the link of the image page.

What I have tried:

1. When I display the image photos I use:

   ```
   window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&amp;p[title]=<?php echo $title; ?>&amp;p[summary]=<?php echo $summary; ?>&amp;p[url]=<?php echo $url; ?>&amp;p[images][0]=<?php echo $image; ?>','sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=548,height=325');
   ```

   where: `$image` is the image src, and `$url` is the separate image page
2. I've created a separate url for the image page, where I simply include only the image, but I have all the `og:title`, `og:image`, `og:type` meta tags, and I have used that url in point #1

Is there a workaround on this?

Many thanks for your time!